# What is a similar solution in Polymer that provides all/almost all features of the useraccounts package in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, authentication, polymer

I'm looking for a solution in Polymer that includes the following features:

- sign in
- sign up
- forgot password
- reset password
- change password
- social sign-in via Facebook
- social sign-in via Google
- secure

Meteor has a package available for this, more details: http://useraccounts.meteor.com/

I'm wondering how others have solved this common problem. We’re using MongoDB and Meteor at the backend, so please do not point out another database eg Firebase as a solution as it would imply changing the whole backend database just for the purpose of handling user sign-in's.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Polymer element for Google signin seems to be the only solution I could find. It's to authenticate with Google for the use of their services like Google Drive or Google+

[Doc to Google Signin element](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-signin)

Comment: Checkout firebase there is an element for that. Firebase provides you with an api to do user authentication etc.  You can always write your own element to wrap your own implementation of user login and management and share it with the world ;-)

Comment: @W3bWizArt I mentioned in my question that I'm using MongoDB for the backend. I don't see the point to add Firebase to it just to manage user accounts which anyway are kept in the backend database. Please note that I don't want to change the backend database just for that purpose.

Comment: Sorry my bad I read it on my phone and missed that.